# Making a cylinder take the shape of an existing object

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a shape which is exactly the shape I need but of horrendous topology.

I thought that if I could add a cylinder over the existing object and get it to inherit the objects shape that could be a way out.  Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Hello could you please show an image of your object or even share it? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: you could look into shape key animation. but first make sure both objects have exactly same vertices. just create the cylinder to have exactly same vertices.

Comment: Thanks Harry but increasing the vertex count was something I'd hoped to gain from this

Comment: The object is this  https://ibb.co/5F4KxZh

Comment: Sure, if you use a cylinder as a Target of a Shrinkwrap modifier, it will allow your shape to be cleaner, have you tried this solution?

Comment: Nope I haven't tried that Moonboots but I sure going to, Thank you!